# How does "target.should be" work in rspec

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I can't figure out what is 'be' when using rpec.

```
target.should be 5
```

I know how to use it, but how is it implemented? Is it something like an operator i.e.

```
target.should.send(:be, 5)
```

How can I implement something similar?

Comment: It's not the most straightforward source, but I would still start by looking at it: https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/blob/master/lib/spec/matchers/be.rb#L236-240

Comment: From the link above: `a.equal?(b)`, which basically means they have the be the same instance (same `#object_id`).

Comment: https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/blob/master/lib/spec/matchers/be.rb#L189 via https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/blob/master/lib/spec/matchers/be.rb#L237-239

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`be` is a method which returns an RSpec Matcher, as mentioned by d11wtq in [a comment above](https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/blob/master/lib/spec/matchers/be.rb#L237-239)

You can implement any other method which returns a matcher, but there are [other, simpler ways](https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/Custom-Matchers) to write a matcher.

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_a_multiple_of do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    actual % expected == 0
  end
end

describe 9 do
  it "should be a multiple of 3" do
    9.should be_a_multiple_of(3)
  end
end
```